# Django and backbone - how to write a view which supports loading elements by ajax and non-ajax for disabled javascript

Tags: ajax, django, backbone.js

I've been wondering how to develop a django view which supports loading objects trough json and also for clients with blocked js it should support non-js fallback - use querysets like ObjectName.objects.filter()

What's the best approach for such views which support dynamic data loading by json and also getting objects without json? Or simply my approach is totally wrong and I should get some more information how to write a ajax-dynamic site like http://www.usatoday.com

```
def index(request):
    q = Page.objects.all()
    return TemplateResponse(request, "orders/order_index.html",
                                {'object_list': q,},)
```

If you need any additional data connected with my question please just ask me.

Update 1 - example:

Index renders initial page you see when you enter the site (example.com)

```
def index(request):
    q = Entry.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', {'object_list': q, })


def detail(request, slug):
    q = get_object_or_404(Entry.objects.all(), slug=slug)
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'blog/templates/blog_detail.html', {'object': q, })
```

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load webdesign %}
{% load markup %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load endless %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    {% paginate object_list %}
    {% for object in object_list %}
        <article>

            <h2>{{ object.title }}</h2>

            <div>

            </div>
            <hr>
            <p>
                {{ object.get_short_text|markdown }}
            </p>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <span class="metadata"><i class="foundicon-clock"></i> {{ object.date_added|date:"j E Y" }} ({{ object.date_added|naturaltime }})</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="button expand read_more" href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{% trans "Read more" %}</a>
            <hr>

        </article>
    {% endfor %}
    {% show_pages %}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

```
non ajax
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2275
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/sass/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/foundicons/foundation_icons_general/stylesheets/general_foundicons.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/foundation/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/foundation/js/vendor/zepto.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/foundation/js/foundation.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/img/navy_blue_min.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/img/sub.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET /site_media/static/foundicons/foundation_icons_general/fonts/general_foundicons.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Mar/2013 15:16:52] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 14
index
ajax
```

Comment: You can always check to see if a request was made via ajax using `request.is_ajax()` and return the appropriate response depending on the type of request.

Comment: I tried with a condition if request.is_ajax() as I understand it correctly I would need to call this view from another view to check if request.is_ajax(). At this point I don't really understand how it should look.

Comment: I've added some sample code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of how you can leverage `request.is_ajax()` to return a different type of response:

```
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render


def your_view(request):
    data = {'foo': 'bar'}
    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
    else:
        return render(request, 'some-template.html', data)
```

Comment: This will not solve the issue I suppose: when I printed request.is_ajax it gets printed two times - first time when I access the page and it returns False and second time when page load is completed and I get True.

I think that it needs a bit different approach or call it from another view but then I can't imagine how the code should look like.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you post your views?

Comment: I am really sorry for slow response. What I am trying to achieve is a single page application which works with and without javascript. 

So when I use navigation the page would be rendered by js/backbone json data from api and when js is turned off it would use normal querysets.

Comment: Others will argue differently, but I wouldn't leverage class-based views here. I would stick with function-based views, as it's simply easier to see what's going on. The code I've posted *does* work, as I've used it countless times to render a template for a normal GET request, and JSON for an Ajax request.

Comment: You're leveraging TemplateResponse which doesn't have a way to respond differently to Ajax requests on its own. Change your views to function-based using my pattern and I think you'll achieve the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for response. I'll check it again :)

Comment: I updated the first post with image and response log for a single user request.

Comment: If you're truly issuing an non-ajax GET, there's no way "ajax" should get printed. I'm not familiar enough with Backbone to tell you exactly why it might be doing that, but I can write a functional test that will prove that `if request.is_ajax()` works as expected.